# List or Enumerate MSForms.dataObject Clipboard Format Identifiers

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, excel-2007

Is it possible to list or enumerate the format identifiers within a MSForms.dataObject Clipboard?

Currently using Excel 2007 VBA...

I have the correct references set up and am able to set the text in the clipboard and can retrieve it again if the format identifier is known and explicitly named, but is it possible to list or loop through all identifiers?  Below is my Non-Working code.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GetTextFromClipboard()
Dim DataObj As MSForms.dataObject
Dim lngCounter As Long

    If DataObj Is Nothing Then Set DataObj = New MSForms.dataObject

    With DataObj
       .SetText "Test", "Custom_1"
       .PutInClipboard
       .SetText "Another Test", "Custom_2"
       .PutInClipboard
       .SetText "Last Test", "Custom_3"
       .PutInClipboard
    End With

    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    'NON-WORKING PORTION BELOW  
    For lngCounter = LBound(Application.ClipboardFormats) To UBound(Application.ClipboardFormats)

            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print Application.ClipboardFormats(lngCounter)
            Debug.Print DataObj.GetText(lngCounter)
            Debug.Print DataObj.GetText(Application.ClipboardFormats(lngCounter))
            On Error GoTo 0

    Next

    'THIS PORTION WORKS 
    Debug.Print DataObj.GetFormat("Custom")
    Debug.Print DataObj.GetText("Custom")

    DataObj.Clear
    Set DataObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

What I'm having issues with is retrieving either the Values (Clipboard Data) and Names of the different Format Identifiers saved within the Clipboard.

Desired End Result Example:

```
  1) "Test", "Custom_1"
  2) "Another Test", "Custom_2"
  3) "Last Test", "Custom_3"
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer but formatting this in the comments would be horrible. I removed `On error resume next` to see where the code was failing. I am testing your code on Excel 2013 as i do not have 2007 but some of this should help you. I don't this you can use `"custom"` for the parameter as it only accepts the following as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textdataformat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CommaSeparatedValue
Html
Rtf
Text
UnicodeText
```

I needed to comment out some of your code as it caused an error for me on several lines.

```
Invalid FORMATETC structure
```

I will come back to why i think this is happening shortly. I wanted to know the friendly name of the xClipBoardFormat Type and not the enum number. So i made the following.

```
Public Function ClipboardFormatToString(value As XlClipboardFormat) As String
    ' This will take the enum value and convert it to a string equivelent.
    Select Case value
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBIFF
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary Interchange file format for Excel version"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBIFF12
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary Interchange file format 12"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBIFF2
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary Interchange file format 2"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBIFF3
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary Interchange file format 3"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBIFF4
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary Interchange file format 4"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBinary
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Binary format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatBitmap
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Bitmap format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatCGM
            ClipboardFormatToString = "CGM format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatCSV
            ClipboardFormatToString = "CSV format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatDIF
            ClipboardFormatToString = "DIF format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatDspText
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Dsp Text format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatEmbeddedObject
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Embedded Object"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatEmbedSource
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Embedded Source"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatLink
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Link"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatLinkSource
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Link to the source file"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatLinkSourceDesc
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Link to the source description"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatMovie
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Movie"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatNative
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Native"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatObjectDesc
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Object description"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatObjectLink
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Object link"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatOwnerLink
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Link to the owner"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatPICT
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Picture"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatPrintPICT
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Print picture"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatRTF
            ClipboardFormatToString = "RTF format"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatScreenPICT
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Screen Picture"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatStandardFont
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Standard Font"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatStandardScale
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Standard Scale"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatSYLK
            ClipboardFormatToString = "SYLK"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatTable
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Table"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatText
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Text"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatToolFace
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Tool Face"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatToolFacePICT
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Tool Face Picture"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatVALU
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Value"
        Case XlClipboardFormat.xlClipboardFormatWK1
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Workbook"
        Case Else
            ClipboardFormatToString = "Unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

Take note of the `Case Else ... "Unknown"` portion. Now, knowing was the formats are i ran this inside your loop. Note that i also had this at the start of my file `Dim strFormat As String` as i am a fan of `Option Explicit`.

```
DataObj.SetText "On a scale of 1 to 10 i am awesome"
DataObj.PutInClipboard
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

For lngCounter = LBound(Application.ClipboardFormats) To UBound(Application.ClipboardFormats)

strFormat = ClipboardFormatToString(Application.ClipboardFormats(lngCounter))
Debug.Print "Format is: " & ClipboardFormatToString(Application.ClipboardFormats(lngCounter))
If strFormat <> "Unknown" Then
    Debug.Print DataObj.GetText(lngCounter)
End If
```

Which nets me the following in my immediate window

```
Format is: Text
On a scale of 1 to 10 i am awesome
Format is: Unknown
```

When i accounted for the "unknown" ClipboardFormats then i was able to return the text without an issue. The number that can be returned that is supposed to be a format is 44 which is not a registered format as per [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/HV080555580.aspx). The only mention i could find of the 44 value is from a post with no real explanation. I include the [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-15047.html) it to show that i tried to make sense of it.

Knowing that you should be able to loop through and work with the identifiers you want.

Comment: Matt, I appreciate your effort and can see you put some time into this response; however, it does not address the actual issue regarding the enumeration of the possible different format identifiers... Your example just shows how to loop through the default elements which I am already able to do. Thank you for the effort though

Comment: Thanks for updating the question as a result